# Unable to load certificate chain to java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a blah.p7b certificate type PKCS#7 which i want to import it to a java keystore using keytool in order to enable HTTPS on **tomcat** , i don't have the alias name and keystore when the certificate was generated i took it from the client whose want to enable https on our web-application server that they use, can this works without having the original alias name and keystore ?
when i tried to import the certificate i used this command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystore -storepass <mypasswd> -alias "myalias"
```

but it gives me this error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for <mydomain>
```

Please help...

Comment: You're using the alias for a different keypair. List the KeyStore to see if there are any other key pairs in there. Yours might be there after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't got the original KeyStore you are hosed. You have to generate a new KeyStore, a new keypair, a new CSR, get it signed, and then import the signed cert and its chain into the KeyStore using the same alias as the keypair.

Comment: Would it change anything if it was a wildcard certificate?

Comment: Nothing will change anything until you have the private key of the certificate,